# Security with Appcelator Titanium

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

I want to use Appcelator Titanium for Mobile App Development,But I am really concerned about the security of my code.

I studied some of the Android apps developed in Appcelator Titanium **but from .apk file ,I am easily able to extract the logic part i.e. .jsfiles,.mp3 files etc, Which means my whole code is not secured.**

Can anyone Please tell me how can I protect my code developed in Appcelator Titanium..?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are  looking at an APK built for distribution in the app store i.e. build with

```
ti build -p android -T dist-playstore
```

Development version are not packed etc. Also generally what ever you use to build your app the resources are fairly easy to extract